# Assign selected cells to variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables, range

I have a vba assignment where I want to assign cell values to a variable. I used `selection.SpecialCells` to find select the relevant cells. Thus I have selected a column containing 11 cells, but with spaces in between. How can I assign this to a variable?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(1000, 3)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Select

Set IsinArray = Selection
```

Comment: What sort of value is being stored? And is it a single value you want stored in the variable at any given point, or do you want the variable to contain multiple values at once? some context of how this variable would be used would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to convert set of numbers into string: "11, 5, 22, etc."?

Comment: The cells contain ISIN codes (two letters followed by numbers). fx US0010246396

Comment: I need to match the ISIN codes with the codes in another excel file and then copy values in another column where the ISIN code matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Remove the `Set` - it is used only to assign objects, not values.
**(2)** Read (and understand) [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
**(3)** Qualify the `Cells` - you need to tell VBA from which worksheet you want the cells.
**(4)** The second parameter in SpecialCells specifies what kind of data you want to read. `2` (`xlTextValues`) says only strings, so numbers are filters out. If you want to read all cells that are not empty, simply omit this parameter.
**(5)** If your Range contains more than one cell, the values are stored in a 2-dimensional array. If your Range contains only one value, the result is a single value, not an array. If `SpecialCells` doesn't find anything (eg, all cells are empty), it will throw a runtime error.
**(6)** Use `Option Explicit` and declare all variables. As the result of the `SpecialCells` can be of different type, use a `Variant`.
**(7)** Split complex statements helps to find errors.

```
Dim r as Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(4, 3), .Cells(1000, 3))
    ' (Synonym to Set r = .Range("C4:C1000")
End With

Dim myVals
On Error Resume Next  ' Handle the possible error that no value was found
myVals = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0

If IsEmpty(myVals) Then
    Debug.Print "No values found."
ElseIf Not IsArray(myVals) Then
    Debug.Print "Only one value found."
Else
    Debug.Print UBound(myVals, 1) & " values found."
End If
```